# Max. number of document realtime listeners

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm wondering whether there is a maximum number of Firestore realtime listeners I can use, and if there is an overhead per listener?

This is for a page in a React web app. I want to monitor changes in all documents within a collection, so I have the option of either using multiple document listeners, or a single collection query listener. The typical number of documents will be 20-30, but could grow to around 100 for edge cases (I won't be setting a limit, and wouldn't intend on using 'limit()'.

The Firestore architecture is along the lines of:

```
  /projects/{project}/sections/{section}
```

Example: A user can edit sections within "project_abc".

I can either setup a single query listener on the 'sections' collection, and then will need to loop through the snapshot (ie multiple docs) on each change, or attach a new document listener to each section (ie. could end up with 30+ listeners).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All of the documented limits of Cloud Firestore are documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas).  Most of the limits are placed on writing of data.  The only limit that would affect your specific case is the number of (unique client socket) connections capped at 1 million.  The listeners themselves are cheap, and you shouldn't be worried about lots of listeners attached to a document.

Comment: Hello Doug, I don't understand it at all. So I can only have 1MM clients(phones) using realtime at the same time? Or I can have up to 1MM `snapshotListeners` running PER CLIENT ?

Comment: @FranciscoDurdinGarcia I have the same doubt. The [official page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) simply says _Maximum concurrent connections for mobile/web clients per database_ is 1 million. So, I assume that it refers to 1 million devices (since _client_ probably means a device rather than a listener)

Comment: A listener is not a client.  A single client can have many listeners added at the same time, and they all share the same, single, client connection for an instance of a running app.  There is a limit on the number of clients, but not the number of total listeners among all the clients.

Comment: @DougStevenson The docs say to keep the number of snapshot listeners per client under 100 though. - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#realtime_updates. Is your answer still relevant?

Answer (score 3):

Update Oct. 2023:
The official docs do not mention a specific limit anymore.

Original answer:

You might want to think about how you structure your listeners as you say their number could grow to around 100 per client. This would exactly hit the recommended limit as documented in the [firebase best practices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#realtime_updates).

Comment: I do not see this guideline anymore in the best practices of Firestore https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#realtime_updates .Can you please confirm if I am looking at the right page?

Comment: yes indeed it does not mention this number anymore. They might have lifted this strict limit. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @tjeisenschenk Hi, any update on Firestore snapshot listener limit? Does this mean 100k users can subscribe to a single document seamlessly?