# What does `client` mean in the firestore documentation

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

On page https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices, I saw this sentence:

> Keep the number of snapshot listeners per client under 100.

I read the page on 2021/02/18, and I haven't found the clear meaning of `client` on that page.

What does `client` mean?  Is it a (service) account? or is it a `firestore.Client` object? If it is a `firestore.Client` object, can I use multiple `firestore.Client` objects as a workaround to `100 snapshot listeners per client` limit?

Answer (score 0):

Per the oficial [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/cloud/FirestoreClient), it refers to the firestore.Client object,

> FirestoreClient provides access to Google Cloud Firestore. Use the
> API to obtain a Firestore instance, which provides methods for
> updating and querying data in Firestore

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56213903/max-number-of-document-realtime-listeners) is a question similar to yours that can enlighten you even more about the difference between Listeners and Clients and how a Client can have multiple listeners.